# illegal invokation error jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
function search()
{    
  var dateFrom = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
  var dateTo = $("#datepickerTo").val();
  var sponsers = $("#storeCheck").val();
  var organiser = $("#organiser").val();
  var sort = $("#sort").val();
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("searchEvents.php", {
        datepickerFrom: datepickerFrom,
        datepickerTo: datepickerTo,
        storeCheck: sponsers,
        organiser: organiser,
        sort: sort
      },
      function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
      });
  });
}
```

Im trying to pass variables from jquery to php but it shows me Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation.Please help!

Comment: Seem like your variable for datepickerFrom, datapickerTo is not exists. Do you mean dateFrom and dateTo??

Comment: you didnt defined two variables like @NorlihazmeyGhazali mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. why are you putting the `$(document).ready()` inside the `search()` function?
2. Change the variable names e.g `datepickerFrom` is not defined.

**Try this**:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        function search()  {  
        var dateFrom = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
        var dateTo = $("#datepickerTo").val();
        var sponsers = $("#storeCheck").val();
        var organiser = $("#organiser").val(); 
        var sort = $("#sort").val();

        $.post("searchEvents.php", { dateFrom:dateFrom, dateTo: dateTo, storeCheck: sponsers,organiser:organiser,sort:sort },function(data) {
         alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
           });


       }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your variable `dateFrom` and `dateTo`. Try change like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function search()
{   

var dateFrom = $("#datepickerFrom").val();
var dateTo = $("#datepickerTo").val();
var sponsers = $("#storeCheck").val();
var organiser = $("#organiser").val(); 
var sort = $("#sort").val();

    $.post("searchEvents.php", { datepickerFrom:dateFrom, datepickerTo:dateTo, storeCheck: sponsers,organiser:organiser,sort:sort }, function(data) {
      alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });

 }
 });
```